# How to commit changes on server and pull updates from code repository without conflict?

Tags: linux, git, gitlab

I pushed latest codes from my GitLab repository. The changes was coming from my local development machine. I've successfully done it using this commands:

```
git push
```

to push my latest changes to my GitLab repository. Now I pulled the updates on server but unfortunately it did not happen successfully since I have uncommitted changes from the server.

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

 modified:   .htaccess
 modified:   composer.json
 modified:   composer.lock

Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
php.ini
php_errorlog
```

These changes makes my git pull failed thus need to commit it first before pulling the updates from GitLab repository. How should we commit it the right way to prevent conflict on server side.

This is actually the scenario:

First I push my changes from local development machine to Gitlab repository. **git command** `git push`

Second I pull code updates from Gitlab repository to my server. **git command** `git pull`

Third I get conflict due to uncommitted changes in server.
**Error conflict:** after done the second step.

```
 Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

 modified:   .htaccess
 modified:   composer.json
 modified:   composer.lock

Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
php.ini
php_errorlog
```

Comment: On your server, have you tried `"(use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)"` for `.htaccess composer.json composer.lock` in the servers working directory and then do a `git pull` from gitlab on the server?

Comment: Those files are fixes that's why I can't discard it. @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: Do you just want to commit from your server to you repo?

Comment: The overall system design for Git means that Git is not a deployment system. If some files need to be changed for deployment purposes, that should be done outside Git. If some files need to be changed to fix bugs, that should be done in Git but *not on the server*. This way there will never be any changes in a server-side Git repository; in fact; the server won't have a Git repository at all, at least not for doing service (it might have a separate, `--bare`, Git repository to receive push requests, if the server is both the Git server *and* the other-service server).

Comment: Yes you have a point @torek. However, my hosting service provider did it themselves as I report those server issues. It so happen that my project deployed to their server does not match with their server setup for instance I'm using php version 7.4 but their server used 7.3 thus some of the php framework packages going to deploy are not working properly. So as alternative they do some tweaks on their server to make it work. Therefore those files affected cannot be done in local development since it only happens on the server side.

Comment: For @DavidC.Rankin . I only want to commit the changes on the server not on the repo since it is a fixed code for the server only not on the project codes itself.

Comment: Yes, in special situations like that, if I can't set up a separate machine (or VM) in which to run their environment, I'd make a new clone on their server, and work in the new clone. Working directly in a non-bare repository *can* work, but it's ... messy; it's way too easy to drop something along the way.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE :** If multiple people are working on the same file, then there is more possibility of getting conflicts. It will be easy to resolve conflicts with **Visual Studio Code Editor**

**Steps to resolve conflicts**

1. Check whether all your change set are correct , validate once and remove /discard all the wanted files which you don't want to commit
2. Enter the command in current work folder `git add .`
3. Then check the staged file with the next command `git status` and validate once like whether the required file only got staged up.
4. Then do `git stash`, which will store your current code with another index
5. Now do `git pull` to pull the changes from the server, which will make your current working repository latest with server
6. Now do `git stash pop` , this will stash the changes which you have done
7. Since you have poped out your changes , if any conflict occurs check the changeset
   if both are needed -  do `Accept Both`,
   if only your changes needed - do `Accept Incoming`,
   if the current changes present in server is needed - `Accept Current`.
8. Again check `git status`, by this you can reverify whether only your changeset is correct
9. Now you can commit your changes to the server

Hope this would be helpful

Comment: There are actually two people working on the project. However, those conflicts occurred on the server only not happening on the remote repository. The conflicts happen on the server and it causes conflict after fixing some server related issues and I cannot discard it since it's a fixed for server issues only not on local development or remote repository. @Kishore Kumar